# Returning range sequence based on input count?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a below table, My aim is to return `StartCount` and `EndCount` to the user based on `@Count` variable value.

By default `StartCount, CurrentCount` in table SequenceMst will be 1.

> If user input `@Count = 10` Then Code should return `StartCount = 1` and
>   `EndCount = 10`
>
> If next user input `@Count = 10` Then Code should return  `StartCount = 11` and `EndCount = 20`
>
> If next user input `@Count = 20`  Then Code should return `StartCount = 21` and `EndCount = 40`

My output is returning 1, 10 range first then 10, 20 but it should be 11 to 21 and 22 should be updated in table in `CurrentCount` column.

```
CREATE TABLE SequenceMst
(
Id INT identity(1,1) primary key
,Code varchar(50)
,StartCount INT
,CurrentCount INT
);

insert into SequenceMst values ('ApForm',1,1);

select * from SequenceMst;

--My Code
DECLARE @Count as INT = 10; -- could be any number as input parameter

DECLARE @CurrentCount        AS INT     
       ,@StartCount          AS INT
       ,@UpdatedCurrentCount AS INT; 

    SELECT @CurrentCount = CurrentCount 
    FROM   SequenceMst
    WHERE  Code = 'ApForm';

    SELECT @UpdatedCurrentCount = (CurrentCount + @Count) - 1
    FROM   SequenceMst
    WHERE  Code = 'ApForm';

    UPDATE SequenceMst
    SET    CurrentCount = @UpdatedCurrentCount + 1
    WHERE  Code = 'ApForm';     

    SELECT @CurrentCount as StartCount, @UpdatedCurrentCount as EndCount;
```

Comment: I've tried your code in my system and got 1-10 and 11-20 as expected. I can't imagine why you're getting 10-20.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. what is the version you are actually working with?